# Query para obtener todos los resultados cuando los valores son iguales en una columna pero distintos en otra, con SQLITE

Tags: sql, sqlite

Utilizando una base de datos SQLITE, tengo una tabla en la que los registros muestran los procesos realizados por cada equipo. La tabla es del estilo:

| id_reg | equip | process |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 2 | B | 5 |
| 3 | A | 2 |
| 4 | B | 2 |
| 5 | A | 6 |
| 6 | A | 1 |
| 7 | A | 6 |
| 8 | B | 5 |

Quiero hacer una query que me permita obtener un listado de todos los procesos y el equipo que los ha hecho, solamente mostrando un registro por cada proceso - equipo, tal que así:

| equip | process |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 6 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 5 |

He probado a realizar la siguiente query:

`SELECT EQUIP, PROCESS FROM table1 GROUP BY PROCESS ORDER BY EQUIP ASC`

Pero el resultado que obtengo no permite mostrar casos en el que el número de proceso es el mismo en dos equipos. El resultado obtenido con dicha query es:

| equip | process |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 6 |
| B | 5 |

No aparece el resultado:

| equip | process |
| --- | --- |
| B | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si ordenas por procesos cuando se de el caso que un proceso lo haya hecho varios equipos solo se mostrara el primero. La query esta bien solo que le sobra el `GROUP BY` y hacer el select con el atributo `SELECT DISTINCT`, esto hara que no se muestren repetidos.

Comment: Hola Eneko, disculpa si el titulo es confuso. Aplicando lo que tu me sugieres no obtengo el resultado deseado, entiendo que la query que dices es: 'SELECT EQUIP, PROCESS FROM table1 ORDER BY PROCESS'. Si aplico esto el resultado me muestra todos los registros, incluidos los repetidos por un mismo equipo.

Comment: Has probado a utilizar el SELECT DISTINCT? Esto solo mostrara los no repetidos. @cgacga

Comment: Ahora si, muchas gracias Eneko.

Comment: Si puedes añadir mi respuesta como la solución lo agradecería, un saludo y Happy coding :)